# Alamofire router modify path parameter

Tags: ios, alamofire

I would like to do something like this using Alamofire 4 router.

```
case .updateUser(_):
        return Constants.Routes.URL_USER_FRAG + "/(id)"

func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
case .updateUser(let parameters):
        urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        urlRequest.addValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
}
```

In the asURLRequest, I want to set the value of `(id)` from parameters like `urlRequest.path.id = parameters.id`

Is this a possibility with Alamofire?